# instantiate object from strings in array php

Tags: php, symfony

I have this array:

```
$methodsOutput = array("MidUpperArmMuscleArea","ArmSpan_HeightEstimation","BMIBeforePregnancy",
                "PregnancyTotalWeightGain","PregnancyWeeklyWeightGain","MS_CurrentBMI_BMIPregnancyWeeks",
                "PregnancyDueDate","PregnancyWeeks","WeightEstimation","WHO_BMI_2000_IdealBMI",
                "WHO_BMI_2000_IdealWeight","WHO_HeightAge_2006_IdealHeight","WHO_WeightAge_2006_IdealWeight");
```

and for each one I have the respective class (all included in file).

How can I instantiate dynamically this.

I try this:

```
foreach($methodsOutput as $method) {
    $$method= new $method();
}
```

but get:

> Fatal error: Class 'MidUpperArmMuscleArea' not found in...

Comment: Do NOT use variable variables. Your code becomes an unmaintainable impossible-to-debug mess.

Comment: if you get `Class '...' not found` then the class is not found. No way around it. If you think the class *should* be found, then test your assumption to be correct.

Comment: @Munir: which is why it's a comment.

Comment: @MarcB: thx. I did not want to be rude

Comment: @Yoshi: If I comment the 'foreach' code and put $instance = new MidUpperArmMuscleArea() works.

Comment: Probably 'Fatal error: Class 'MidUpperArmMuscleArea' not found in...' is from another piece of code, not this one.

Comment: A friend who works with symfony2 helped me. I forgot mark tag Symfony2. Thx all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have that class "MidUpperArmMuscleArea" ? 
You could to use class_exists to test.

Comment: Realy. The class is 'MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\MidUpperArmMuscleArea'. Cause I am using Symfony2. 
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Objectively, this looks like a really bad way of doing this..

Anyway, that's not what you want to hear.

The class 'MidUpperArmMuscleArea' must really not exist in that context, as your syntax is correct. Since you mention all these classes are in the same file, are you defining them after you are executing this code?

Comment: Sorry all!

I am new here and I forgot to check the tag 'Symfony2' in the question.

The array should be:

    $methodsOutput = array("MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\MidUpperArmMuscleArea","MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\ArmSpan_HeightEstimation",...);

and now works!

but I change this... I will pass this variables in YML file.

Thx all!
and sorry again.